# Create a prompt on Javascript Button

Tags: javascript, custom-button, custom

I have a custom JavaScript Button which makes a call out.

Button Code as Below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/14.0/apex.js")} 
sforce.apex.execute("ClientPortal_lead","Lead_Approval", {email:"{!Lead.Email}"}); 
window.alert("Data sent to Client Portal" );
```

I want to prompt a window before making a callout. I want to implement this to avoid duplicate callouts if a user clicks the button twice by mistake.

I tried the following:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} 

var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to convert the Lead); 
if (r == true) { 
sforce.apex.execute("ClientPortal_lead","Lead_Approval", {email:"{!Lead.Email}"}); 
} else { 

}
```

But I am getting unexpected token Illegal error.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your approach is correct. You are only missing an `"` after **Lead** in line number 4.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")} 

var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to convert the Lead"); 
if (r == true) { 
sforce.apex.execute("ClientPortal_lead","Lead_Approval", {email:"{!Lead.Email}"}); 
} else { 

}
```

Comment: Thank you Manjit, I am newbie developer , missing on these small things :)